# Can't add category to fresh Magento site - "Please wait" and frameception

Tags: magento

A picture speaks a thousand words, so: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIecM.jpg).

When I go to add a category (Catalogue -> Manage Categories), the window freezes and I'm stuck with that until I refresh. I've tried reinstalling, no dice. Any ideas? This is on Windows Server 2012 with nginx.

Relevant access.log:

```
[20/Aug/2015:09:45:51 -0700] "POST /index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/f718fcd0af210fb5bd16ebf30f5988ba/?isAjax=true HTTP/1.1" 200 95941 "http://10.0.0.13:81/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/66332105b3d3fa3670804804061e450f/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my own. My nginx rewrite configuration wasn't quite right, and the ?isAjax=true query string was being ignored. Ensure you have this inside your server block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

Rather than using pathinfo in the PHP block.